# maven: simple questions about mvn options

Tags: maven, compilation

I tried searching on Google about these and cant really find any thing.

mvn --define : what does it do, how can i use it and for what?

in the maven-compiler-plugin entry (in my POMs) I added

```
 <*verbose>true<*/verbose>
```

I added it to see if it prints out the JAVA_HOME but when i ran the mvn install (in my project directory) but nothing extra ordinary came out as a verbose for compile (just warnings that were coming before as well) even mvn clean compile doesn't give me anything. is there an option to echo the JAVA_HOME when doing compile?

(Disclaimer: I am having some javascript error on this site since yesterday on my work pc :Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.  So... i cant really add comments some how from my work pc. Will reply from home though. sorry for delay inadvance...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes using **mvn -X** clean will display the Java Home details. Please find the output here

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 02:44:56-0600)
Maven home: C:\FlyingSaucer\MAVEN\apache-maven-3.0.4
**Java version: 1.6.0_25, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre**
```

Comment: Been using -X since that time and it has helped.. OH it has helped so much... awesome, bit too verbose but when there are errors, more the better

Answer (score 0):

`mvn --help` should answer all the above questions.

Cut/pasting relevant output of `mvn --help`,

```
-D,--define <arg>                      Define a system property
```

For instance, `mvn -DskipTests package`  (compile and create a package skipping tests)

As for information of JAVA_HOME

`mvn -v`  should give this information

Also, you can run `mvn -X`, which will give a lot of debug information.